# How to display N snackbar in a single page with scaffold?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to send a reset password link to users email.

Case 1: Display a snackbar when User has no email registered.
Case 2: Display a snackbar when email is sent.
Case 3: Display a snackbar if error.

```
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

This is the build function:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: InkWell(...
```

This function Displays the snackbar:
//SnackBar

```
  void showInSnackBar(String value) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(value),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'OKAY',
        onPressed: () {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
```

I am calling show the snackbar for this button:

```
 CustomButton(
            name: 'Get Confirmation Email',
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            onPressed: () async {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                try {
                  //Check if email already exist
                  List<String> res =
                      await _auth.checkEmail(_emailController.text);
                  print(res);
                  if (res == ['password']) {
                    await _auth.resetPassword(_emailController.text);
                    showInSnackBar('Email sent.Check your mail');
                  } else {
                    showInSnackBar('Email is not registered');
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                  showInSnackBar(e);
                }
              }
            },
          )
```

Output:[password]
***Problem:***
on the UI it shows:`Email is not registered`,but the it should be `Email sent.Check your mail`.
I do not unserstand what is wrong here.Is it not getting the right context?

Answer (score 0):

you just test your condition like

```
  String res = await _auth.checkEmail(_emailController.text);
  print(res);
  if (res=="password") {
                    await _auth.resetPassword(_emailController.text);
                    showInSnackBar('Email sent.Check your mail');
                  }
```